# Trying to change the color of clicked Three.js object, but the color of all objects in scene get changed

Tags: javascript, three.js

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/f17Lz5ux/2539/

Here is the magic part that happens on the `mousedown` event:

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( [mesh1, mesh2, mesh3] );

if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
    console.log(intersects[ 0 ].object)
    intersects[ 0 ].object.material.color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff );
}
```

The idea is that when the user clicks, a Ray is created at that point, and any intersections are found. The color of that object is then changed to a random new color. What is happening, though, is that all of the objects get their color changed, even though they are not included in the `intersects` array (if you check the console, you'll see that the clicked object gets printed)

What gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. It's because that code is actually changing the color of the Material of the object, and since all of the objects share the same material, they all see the color change.

The solution that I moved to creates a new material when the user clicks, and applies it to the object.